# Connecting to IEX with Pandas Datareader

Tags: python, pandas, data, information-retrieval

My Problem is regarding Algorythmic trading. I hope this is the right site for this kind of Question. In specific I try to connect to the "iex" API via the pandas Data reader to retrieve some historical stock data.
After searching around and trying several methods I came up with this code here:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import os


#How to get historical Stock data

symbols = "FB" #Stock Kürzel
start = datetime(2018, 9, 1)
end = datetime(2018, 10, 2)

DataframeStock = pdr.DataReader(symbols, data_source = "iex", start = start, end = end, api_key = "pk_1234")

print(DataframeStock)
```

As far as I can tell everything looks fine and like in the tutorials (for example here: https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-iex) (I registered on https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/ and Iam using my own public key).
Unfortunately I get this error message:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cloud.iexapis.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url:
>   /stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=FB&types=chart&range=2y&token=pk_8dfc5c0ae37940e78a2a0037bed89d5b
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

It sound like I tried to often, but there shouldnt be to much of a restriction and overall I tried it less then 50 times and today stopped at 2 tries.

Thanks alot in advance.